# acabar una instrucción antes de ejecutar otra en javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, objeto

Buenassss

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ejecute primero la instrucción Dom y cuando lo muestre en pantalla borrando lo que haya anteriormente, ejecute el alert?
Por ahora solo consigo que se borre lo anterior cuando cierra el alert, viéndoselos en pantalla una información que contradice al alert. Algo más profesional que un Delay o un `location.reload(true);` o similar

```
document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML= 'lo que sea';        
alert("loquees ");}
```

Comment: Realmente por jerarquía primero rellena #pr con 'lo que sea' y después salta el alert. Solo que es en milisegundos, y parece que no. Si pusieras un delay al alert, seguro que lo ves, prueba esto:

setTimeout(function(){alert("loquees ")},5000);